# Installing SSL certs with nginx on Amazon EC2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, ssl, ssl-certificate

I finally got a cert from an authority and am struggling to get things working.  I've created the appropriate combined certificate (personal + intermediate + root) and nginx is pointing to it. I got an elastic IP and connected it to my EC2 instance. My DNS records point to that IP.  But when I point the browser to the hostname, I get the standard "Connection Untrusted" bit, with ssl_error_bad_cert_domain. Port 443 is open - I can get to the site over https if I ignore the warning. Weird thing is, under technical details, it lists the domain I tried to access as valid!

When I try and diagnose with ssl testing sites, they don't even detect a certificate!

What am I missing here?

domain is yanlj.coinculture.info.  Note I've got coinculture.info running on a home server without a dedicated IP and have the same problem, but I'll be moving that to the same EC2 instance as soon as I figure this thing out.  I thought the elastic IP would solve things but it hasn't

Nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name localhost;

  ssl                  on;
  ssl_certificate      /home/ubuntu/certs/startssl/ssl-unified.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /home/ubuntu/certs/startssl/ssl.key;

  keepalive_timeout    70;

  #ssl_session_timeout  5m;

  ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
 #ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
 #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

  root /home/ubuntu/programming/YanlJ;
  index index.php index.html;

      location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;  # this line was causing the index.php file to be loaded twice...
      }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

                # With php5-cgi alone:
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi.conf;
        }

  try_files $uri $uri.php $uri.html =404;
}
```

and results of curl -kv `https:// ELASTIC_IP:`

`* Rebuilt URL to: https:// 54.186.114.3/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 54.186.114.3...
* Connected to 54.186.114.3 (54.186.114.3) port 443 (#0)
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.0 / DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=CA; ST=Ontario; L=Guelph; O=Ethan Buchman; CN=blog.coinculture.info; emailAddress=webmaster@coinculture.info
*        start date: 2014-05-29 15:10:52 GMT
*        expire date: 2016-05-29 10:44:27 GMT
*        issuer: C=IL; O=StartCom Ltd.; OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing; CN=StartCom Class 2 Primary Intermediate Server CA
*        SSL certificate verify ok.`

Comment: Show us your nginx configs.

Comment: nginx config: http://pastebin.com/MJ6dG0Rw

Comment: Please edit your question and include that config. Links to the config are not useful.

Comment: Did you recently change the dns for yanlj.coinculture.info. I'm getting that the host is over at godaddy, which is probably why the testing sites don't see anything. Can you also provide the output of curl -kv [https://Elastic_IP](https://Elastic_IP)?

Comment: the domain name was bought with godaddy, but I've always hosted myself. I had changed some DNS stuff a few days ago. I can get to the sites no problem, even through https, I just can't get the cert to verify.

Comment: listen 443 ssl;  and yanlj.coinculture.info has no DNS record...

Comment: If you are able to get to the site over https, what is the result of curl -v (https://yanlj.coinculture.info)[https://yanlj.coinculture.info]. You probably also DNS issues, and I'd recommend testing your site later over a cellphone connection, to ensure it isn't a firewall or /etc/hosts override that allows you  to connect.

Comment: Ya I get the same result over my 4G connection that I do on my wifi.

Answer (score 1):

I see that `coinculture.info` has five authoritative DNS servers. Three of them refuse to resolve `yanlj.coinculture.info`, and the other two give me the IP address `184.168.221.12`. That does not look like an EC2 IP address. That IP address is registered to GoDaddy, and it appears there is a broken firewall in front of that address. I get timeout when trying to connect to port 443 on it.

- Name Server:NS1.WORDPRESS.COM
- Name Server:NS2.WORDPRESS.COM
- Name Server:NS3.WORDPRESS.COM
- Name Server:NS15.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
- Name Server:NS16.DOMAINCONTROL.COM

Comment: +1 for actually checking whois

Comment: brilliant and correct. Yet when I punch in yanlj.coinculture.info in my browser, it does direct me to the right ip of my ec2 instance (54.186.114.3). So why the different ip resolutions?

Comment: @Ethan Which DNS server are you querying? Could that DNS server have cached some other records?

Comment: Google. But OpenDNS giving me same thing. So maybe the dns is routing to godaddy, and godaddy is routing back to the elastic ip, but why it only works sometimes and why the cert doesnt verify I dont know.

Comment: @Ethan I am pretty sure they are both using anycast, so if we both query them, we will be reaching different DNS servers. There is a way to look up the unicast address of the DNS server one is reaching, but they do not respond to DNS queries send to their unicast address, so that's not very useful either. You could check something else, what is the TTL of the record they are serving? `dig -t a yanlj.coinculture.info` should tell you. Also, you still have failures on 60% of your authoritative DNS servers, that's not helping.

Comment: Ok so I'm sure you've all gathered I'm total newb with this DNS thing and have just been hacking to try and make things work.  Spoke to a godaddy person.  Removed the wordpress name servers (they were there for a subdomain), and fixed my A record, which was pointing to the 184 address, whereas subdomain forwarding was set to the 54 address.